# Preseed Failed with wget

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, wget, preseed

I have this strange issue. I am doing a netboot + using local mirrors of trusty 14.04
I have done the following to PXE boot the installer

```
label trusty-amd64-manual
kernel images/ubuntu-installer/trusty/amd64/linux
append vga=normal initrd=images/ubuntu-installer/trusty/amd64/initrd.gz debian-installer/locale=en_GB console-setup/layoutcode=gb  preseed/url=http://blah.com/kickstarts/ubuntu/precise-amd64.cfg
```

Which works fine, the installer loads and starts the process. I can see from the logs that it does a wget on http://blah.com/kickstarts/ubuntu/precise-amd64.cfg and saves it in /tmp/debconf-seed

Which is correct.

The strange thing is that as soon as it as does the wget it does another one but just to the root directory i.e 
wget http://blah.com and saves it to the same place /tmp/debconf-seed so now the installer will fail with a corrupted preseed config

my pressed file looks like this

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string 
d-i debconf/priority select critica
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string blah
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/codename string trusty
d-i mirror/suite string trusty
```

Any help would be great

Thanks
A